# find duplicate pairs in sql table and update values for 1 of each duplicate pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with 1800 entries. 900 entries are duplicates of the other 900 by values in a number of fields, example contactFirstName and contactLastName, however one of each duplicate pair contains data which the other does not, example PhoneNumber. The duplicates which contain the additional data, ie: phoneNumber, have a statusID=10 and the duplicates without the phoneNumber data have statusID=2.
How can I find the duplicate pairs by contactFirstName and ContactLastName, then for each pair (remember-there are 900 pairs) copy the phoneNumber data in the duplicate with statusID=2 into the phoneNumber field in the duplicate with statusID=10 (but only if the destination field value is 'NULL').

I hope my explanation is clear. I Would be very grateful of any help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table with itself, and update the one with status id 10.

Example (SQL Server syntax):

```
update
  a
set
  phoneNumber = b.phoneNumber
from
  TheTable a
  inner join TheTable b on b.contactFirstName = a.contactFirstName and b.contactLastName = a.contactLastName and b.statusID = 2
where
  a.statusID = 10 and a.phoneNumber is null
```

Comment: Hi Guffa, Brilliant - this is a life saver - Thanks. The final line should read; 'where a.statusID = 2 and a.phoneNumber is null'. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mios: Right, I see that it says in the description of the data that the phone number is in the record with status id 10, I was focusing on description of the solution, where it says the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET PhoneNumber = (SELECT t2.PhoneNumber
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.StatusID = 2
                   AND t2.contactFirstName = table.contactFirstName
                   AND t2.ContactLastName = table.ContactLastName)
WHERE PhoneNumber IS NULL
AND StatusID = 10;
```